# How to show more lines in ListView on user click?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a `ListView`, where the row layout has `TextView` with two lines limit:

```
android:lines="2"
```

So, by default each ListView row displayed like:

```
  this is line 1 of the row 1
  this is line 2 of the row 1
  ---------------------------
  this is line 1 of the row 2
  this is line 2 of the row 2
```

I would like to show/hide all lines for the particular row, when user clicks on the row. Let's say user clicked on the row 1, I would like to show something like:

```
  this is line 1 of the row 1
  this is line 2 of the row 1
  this is line 3 of the row 1
  this is line 4 of the row 1
  ---------------------------
  this is line 1 of the row 2
  this is line 2 of the row 2
```

I was thinking about `ExpandableListView` usage, but seems its purpose is different.

How can I implement what I am looking for?

Comment: It may just be me, but you may need to post some more information on what exactly is happening here, I am not quite following.

Comment: @gh123man, I've added the example

Comment: why can't you just invoke `textView.setLines(4)` on item click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've used the following code (allows to have only one item opened):

```
private int openedItem;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    openedItem = -1;

...

adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch(viewId) {
        case R.id.sms_body:
            // override this to be able to handle open/closed listview items
            // see also onListItemClick below
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));

            if (cursor.getPosition() == openedItem) {
                textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            } else {
                textView.setMaxLines(2);
            }   
            return true;


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sms_body);            
        if (openedItem == position) {
            textView.setMaxLines(2);
            openedItem = -1;
        } else {
            textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            openedItem = position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // call this to close all other opened rows
        }      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot get the selected index");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you have a custom list adapter and a list view item layout. 
Wrap all of your lines in some layout.
Give that layout an ID.
Reference the ID in your code and create a view object for it.

Implement a method of your list adapter that does something like:

```
public void toggleVisible() {
    if (viewContainingLines.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        viewContainingLines.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else 
        viewContainingLines.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

attach an onItemClickListener to the list view.

And do something to the effect of - When a user clicks an item, call a that function in your list adapter that toggles the visibility.

You can further extend that method to put some default view in its place, or make something else visible.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change dynamically the maximum number of lines for the `TextView` you use in the row, for example:

```
textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Here is the function I created that I execute every time a row is clicked:

```
private void rowItemExpand(){
        try {
            //Get back the last textview touched 
            TextView textView = lastTouchedTextView;

            boolean fullText;
            if(textView.getTag() == null){
                fullText = false;
            } 
            else {
                fullText = (Boolean) textView.getTag();
            }

            if(fullText){
                textView.setMaxLines(mPrefs.getListViewMaxLines());
                //Keep a flag to show the textview is opened
                textView.setTag(false);
            }
            else{
                textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                textView.setTag(true);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"rowItemExpand - Cannot get the selected index");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like on click I should change this value for already opened row. And, with this approach I faced with the following issue - if I click and then scroll, then some random row is getting opened.

Comment: @LA_ I editted Yoann's answer, once he approves it you will see my solution to that problem.

Comment: bclymer actually I could not approve it, it was rejected at first. Anyway I see your idea, it is kind of what I did in my app, I will update my answer to show it.

Comment: @LA_ to avoid the scrolling problem I added tags on the rows to be sure this kind of behavior never happens. If all the lines --> true, otherwise, false.

Comment: Hmm.. Still it shows some random rows as opened when click and then scroll. My code is like below: `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_body);`  Is there any mistake?

Comment: I also tried to attach tags to the `v` instead of `v.findViewById(R.id.text_body)` - it doesn't help. Logging shows that view id is re-used when I scroll. I click on different rows, but log shows one value like `android.widget.TextView@4054fb50`.

Comment: This answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8058520/604388 - also says that `setTag` shouldn't be used with `ListView`. @bclymer, could you please post your code as separate answer?